# Database design for a tv series app

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm developing a web application about TV shows. And i need help with the database design.

I made a list of what i need, but i can't figure out how to design it. I have the basic tables. Series, episodes, seasons etc. What i can't do is how to relate people with episodes/series. Here is my list:

### There should be multiple `people` type. Actor/director/writer/guest etc.

I don't think creating seperate table for each type is a good idea. So there should be one `people` table. And i need to store the type somewhere.

### A person may be in 1 or many series.

This can be done with `people_serie` table with foreign keys to `people` and `series` tables. But i need a way to relate a person to `episodes` too.

### An actor may play 1 or many roles.

This can be done with `person_role` table.

### This is where its getting complicating.

- A role may be in 1 or many episodes in a serie.
- A person may belong to more than one type in a serie. Ex: actor AND director

I hope i make it clear what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're correct not to split the `People` table.

the first thing to do is add a `Roles` table, that will contain role id and role title (each column should be unique - you don't want 2 different ids for the `Actor` role...)

```
TblRoles
RoleId    RoleTitle
-------------------
1         Director
2         Writer
3         Actor
```

Then you add a `PersonToSeries` table, that will hold it's own id, the person's id and the series's id.
This table will hold every person ever working on that series, being a regular staff member or a 1 episode guest.

```
TblPersonToSeries
PTSId   PersonId   SeriesId  
---------------------------
1       1          1
2       3          8
3       4          7
```

The next table you will need is a `PersonToEpisode` table, that will hold the `PersonToSeries` id and the episode id, and the role id.
In this table you only need to keep integer ids so it's very light weight, and you will specify for each record in `PersonToSeries` the episodes it is relevant for.

```
TblPersonToEpisode
PTEPTSId     RoleId
-------------------
1            2 
2            3
3            1
```

When a person is usually the director of a series, but makes a guess appearance in an episode of that series, you can simply add 2 rows in `PersonToEpisode` for that `PersonToEpisode` with a different role id. (one for `Actor` and one for `Director`)

```
TblPersonToEpisode
PTEPTSId     RoleId
-------------------
13           1 
13           2
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What about types? Should i add a string column to `PersonToSeries` table to indicate the type?

Comment: What do you mean by `type`?

Comment: Person type. Actor/director/writer etc.